# Theta-dependence of massive Schwinger model

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, electric-fields, field-theory, hamiltonian-formalism, topology

I've read in [Coleman's paper on the massive Schwinger model](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0003491676902803) (and in other papers on the same topic, like [this one](https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.07885)) that the model's *Hamiltonian* contains a topological $\theta$-term. However, if I write down the *Lagrangian* of the model (see p. 362 of [Tong's lecture notes on gauge theory](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/gaugetheory.html)),

$$
\mathcal{L}= \frac{1}{2e^2}E_x^2 +\frac{\theta}{2\pi}E_x+i\bar{\psi}_xD_x\psi_x - i m \bar{\psi}_x\psi_x,
$$
and perform a Legendre transformation $$\mathcal{H}(E_x)=E_x\pi_x-\mathcal{L}$$ with

$$
\mathbf{\pi}_x=\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial E_x}= \frac{1}{e^2}E_x+\frac{\theta}{2\pi},
$$

then the resulting Hamiltonian is *independent* of $\theta$:

$$
\mathcal{H}= \frac{1}{2e^2}E_x^2 -i\bar{\psi}_xD_x\psi_x + i m \bar{\psi}_x\psi_x.
$$

Now my question is: Is there any Hamiltonian formulation of the Schwinger model in terms of the electric field $E_x$, which is equivalent to the above Lagrangian formulation, while both formulations contain a $\theta$-term? This question is somewhat related to [my previous question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/476230/).

Answer (score 2):

The last expression written in the question is not yet the Hamiltonian. It is the energy function. Although it is numerically equal to the Hamiltonian, but it is expressed in terms of the electric field which is the time derivative of the vector potential $A_x(x)$. 
$$\mathcal{E}= \frac{1}{2e^2}E_x^2 -i\bar{\psi}_xD_x\psi_x + i m \bar{\psi}_x\psi_x$$
In a Hamiltonian, all the time derivatives of the canonical variables should be replaced by their expressions in terms of the canonical momenta by means of the Legendre transform.
Therefore,  the expression for the Hamiltonian density should be:
$$\mathcal{H}= \frac{ e^2}{2}(\pi_x - \frac{\theta}{2\pi})^2 -i\bar{\psi}_xD_x\psi_x + i m \bar{\psi}_x\psi_x$$
Now, the Hamiltonian is expressed in terms of the correct variables and the dependence on the theta parameter is explicit.

This substitution is not just formal, because in the quantum theory, the canonical momentum is represented by the derivative of the canonical coordinate. (In our case, it is the functional derivative, because it is field theory), thus:

$$\mathbf{\hat{\pi}}_x(x)=i\hbar\frac{\delta}{\delta A_x(x)}$$
Thus:

$$\mathcal{\hat{H}}= \frac{ e^2}{2}(i\hbar\frac{\delta}{\delta A_x(x)} - \frac{\theta}{2\pi})^2 -i\hat{\bar{\psi}}_xD_x\hat{\psi}_x + i m \hat{\bar{\psi}}_x\hat{\psi}_x$$

Geometrically, the energy function is a function over the tangent bundle $TM$ of the configuration space, spanned be the coordinates and velocities, while the Hamiltonian is a function on the cotangent bundle $T^*M$, spanned by the canonical coordinates and momenta. This fact is thoroughly explained in [Foundation of mechanics](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=YAEKBAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=abraham%20marsden%20foundations%20of%20mechanics&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiHz5Wj6fnhAhVHxaYKHe_NCVEQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=abraham%20marsden%20foundations%20of%20mechanics&f=false)  by Abraham and Marsden (Chapter 3).

In $1+1$ dimensions, when the base manifold is the circle $S^1$, the effect of the theta term is manifested solely in the zero mode:
$$\phi(t) = \int_0^{2\pi R} A_x(x, t) dx$$
The Lagrangian, restricted to the zero mode is given on page 321 of Tong's lectures. This is an Aharonov-Bohm Lagrangian on a ring. It has a quantum mechanical theta term. The above Hamiltonian analysis was performed for this quantum mechanical problem by Tong and the Schrödinger equation was explicitly solved.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I know that the Hamiltonian is explicitly theta-dependent when expressed in terms of the canonical variables. However, Coleman and others express the Hamiltonian in terms of the *electric field* and then add an electric background field proportional to theta. This is what I don't understand.

Comment: I don't have Coleman's article, but as I see in the second reference by Zache et al. (quoting Coleman), they use an alternative Hamiltonian in which the theta term is absorbed in the fermion mass term (as a complex mass) (Equation 1). Do you need an explanation how to get this form of the Hamiltonian? because it was not mentioned in the question.

Comment: Sorry for my late response to your comment. Yes, I don't understand how Zache et al. can absorb the $\theta$-term in the fermion mass term if they formulate the Hamiltonian $\mathcal{H}(E_x)$ in terms of the electric field and not in terms of the canonical momenta. In the Lagrangian, I can easily shift the $\theta$-dependence from the $\theta$-term to the fermion mass term using the anomaly equation. However, if the Hamiltonian $\mathcal{H}(E_x)$ in my question is independent of $\theta$, then I cannot (by hand) introduce a $\theta$-dependence in the fermion mass term, right?

Comment: It is possible to use the Hamiltonian written in the last equation in the question. But, in this case the boundary conditions of the wave functions (assuming space is a circle: $x\in S^1$) must be changed in order to obtain the same spectrum of the Hamiltonian written in terms of the canonical momenta. For example, for the zero-mode theory we must have:  $\Psi(\phi = 2\pi) = e^{i\frac{\phi\theta}{2 \pi}}\Psi(\phi = 0)$…

Comment: The answer to the question, why for the Hamiltonian written in terms of the canonical momenta we use the ordinary periodic wave functions, while in the Hamiltonian written with the electric field we use wave functions with the shifted boundary conditions has no mathematical answer….

Comment: Its justification lies solely in the fact that Aharonov-Bohm effect has been observed, please see for example Landsman and Linden https://www.math.ru.nl/~landsman/NPB2.pdf , page 156. Anyway, keeping the rules of the standard canonical analysis scheme would lead directly to the correct Hamiltonian  .

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. Do you have a reference for your claim that we *always* use shifted boundary conditions when we write the Hamiltonian in terms of the electric field? I haven't found this statement in the Landsmann and Linden reference.

Comment: Zache et al. claim that they use periodic boundary conditions, but they add a term $(eθ/2π)E_x$ to their Hamiltonian $\cal{H}$$(E_x)$, which is equivalent to having $\exp(iθγ_5)$ in the mass term. Doesn't this contradict your statement that we need to use shifted (instead of periodic) boundary conditions if we write down the Hamiltonian in terms of the electric field? If so, does this mean that Zache's ansatz is wrong?

Comment: So, can we really write down the Hamiltonian in the last equation in the question plus the term $(eθ/2π)E_x$ (as Zache et al. claim), and if so, do we need shifted boundary conditions or periodic ones (as Zache et al. use)? If such a θ-term corresponds to an electric background field (as Coleman argues), why do Zache et al. write: "To obtain a finite-dimensional Hilbert space, we drop the single remaining bosonic mode describing a constant background field."?

Comment: When you add a term $(eθ/2π)E_x$ to the Hamiltonian, you get up to a constant the same Hamiltonian that I wrote with the canonical momentum $\pi_x$ replaced by $E_x$, thus you should use the periodic boundary condition, just as in the above explanation. Please see Appendix D especially footnote 27 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.00501.pdf Gaiotto et al.

Comment: As for your second remark (finite Hilbert space). They are not referring to whether to use the periodic or the shifted Boundary conditions. They use the periodic ones, but they constrain the field to vanish at one point. In this case they will not have the zero mode that Tong talked about on page 321. This is important to them, because the Gauss law constraint reduces the original dimension of the Hilbert space of each oscillator mode (infinite-dimensional) to a spin (finite-dimensional), except for the zero mode which remains an oscillator.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your remarks, especially the second one was very helpful! Concerning the first one, I don't see how "$π_x$ replaced by $E_x$" can work, because we need to use the proper relation $π_x=E_x/e^2+θ/2π$, which then cancels the θ-dependence in $\cal{H}$$(E_x)$ and brings us back to the Hamiltonian in the last equation in the question. This is exactly the key point of my question: how is it possible to derive the Hamiltonian $\cal{H}$$(E_x)⊃E^2_x/2e^2+E_xθ/2π$ (up to a constant) from the original Lagrangian?

Comment: What I meant is the following: First in my Opinion, they meant adding the negative of $E_xθ/2π$ to their Hamiltonian, secondly, if you complete the squares you get $\frac{1}{2}(E_x - θ/2π)^2- θ/8π^2$. This Hamiltonian looks (up to a constant) just like the Hamiltonian that I wrote with $\pi_x$ replaced by $E_x$ (and putting $e=1$, which is the normalization that they adopted)…

Comment: The fact is that commutators of $E_x$ and $\pi_x$ with the vector potential are identical because they differ by a constant. So, I merely meant that people use them interchangeably in an abuse of notation and there is no real physics behind this sentence.